# Should we create db indexes for rows that have equal number of reads/search and writes?

Tags: sql, database, performance, indexing

When creating indexes, if I understand right, it increases read speed.

But what if you update a column included in the index everytime you read them. For example a date column (last_checked) that we update every time we select them from the database.

In this scenario, is it still beneficial to create an index?

Comment: Indexes do NOT improve READ speed. They improve SEARCH/SORT speed. As a general rule, when you hesitate, don't index. I can always do it later if/when you have a performance issue.

Comment: Also depends upon number of rows your table tend to have, on an average. Indexes make sense only if you have huge number of rows.